# How to rollback on Tomcat in case of unstable build using Jenkins?

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, pipeline, devops

I am using Jenkins to set-up a DevOps pipeline for a Java project. And am stuck at one scenario of deployment. If somehow there has to be roll-back of build on Tomcat server and build that has to replace this one has to be last stable build.
Suppose build#20 is deployed on server which is stable and build#21 is deployed in next build cycle but after deployment its found that this new build has issues. Now i want to replace this build by the previous build that is build#20. 
The plugin I am using on Jenkins doesn't provide the facility of roll-back. Please help me out. 
Plugin for deployment : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just re-build build#20, call it build#22, and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

"Deploy" your build results to a *deploy-candidate* location and only (really) deploy them to Tomcat from there after it has turned out that your complete build process is stable.